# How to compose a command using a for-loop counter and evaluate it in Julia

Tags: plotly, julia, metaprogramming

I've made a function to create a figure with N subplots in Plotly. To hide the x-axis labels of these subplots I want to execute, inside this function, for example for N=5

```
relayout!(p, xaxis_showticklabels=false)
relayout!(p, xaxis2_showticklabels=false)
relayout!(p, xaxis3_showticklabels=false)
relayout!(p, xaxis4_showticklabels=false)
```

Since I don't know that number N of subplots a priori, I'd like to do this in a loop, employing the for-loop counter **n** in the command ...xaxis**n**_...

I've tried to construct the string and then parse it using eval(Meta.parse(expr)) but that doesn't work since eval only works in global scope.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it is time to refactor `xaxis??_showticklabels` into a vector? Then a normal `for` loop would work and the code will be easier to modify/extend.

Comment: That's a really bad interface with awkward naming. Is that part of plotly, or is it your own code? If it is the latter, you should fix it. If it's the former, I'd consider quitting plotly.

Comment: It seems that, ff the subplot grid is simple, let's say just a vertical stack of 5 subplots, then the make_subplots() command permits a shared_xaxes=true option that sets everything beautifully (https://plotly.com/julia/subplots/) Nevertheless, for a more complicated layout (for example, 5 rows of subplots in the left column and one large multirow subplot in the right column), that shared_xaxes=true option does unfortunately not work, and the options for each axis need to be set manually (or at least I do not know how to do it otherwise), i.e. remove x ticks and match x axis to first one.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside "ugly API" comments (and, honestly the API *is* ugly) I understand that you have function such as:

```
f(a; a1=0,a2=0,a3=0) = a+a1+2a2+3a3
```

And you want to call programmatically in a loop something like `f(100, a1=1)`, `f(100, a2=2)`, `f(100, a3=3)`.

This can be accomplished in Julia without resorting to meta-programming by the following code:

```
julia> [f(100; Symbol("a$i")=>i) for i in 1:3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 101
 104
 109
```

As you can see in Julia pairs can be used to programmatically generate kwargs

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it working following your example. I just started with Julia a few weeks ago after years working only in matlab, so I am still getting used to the paradigms of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the canonical example given by Przemyslaw Szufel to my particular problem, this seems to do the trick:

```
relayout!(p; xaxis_showticklabels=false)=>false)
for i = 2:N
    relayout!(p; Symbol("xaxis$i"*"_showticklabels")=>false)
end
```

Comment: You can also write `Symbol("xaxis", i, "_showticklabels")`, which I kind of prefer.